# how do i manage extreme lfs from local to remote simply using any vcs[e.g. git, svn etc.]?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial

i've read many articles but not found yet. currently i'm working on git lfs files with python and cpp but the files[images, shared object, videos etc.] are extremely huge{600 MB}.. so which vcs is great for it. currently i'm working with git but it's very time consuming and painful. sometimes it's failed to commit in my i5 machine. so how do it simply.

Comment: Have you tried [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com)?

Comment: What kind of files of these? How often do they really change?

Comment: look at my updated index. btw i'm working on music files too.

Comment: Mercurial also has '[largefiles](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LargefilesExtension)' extension, distributed with TortoiseHg.